# Find the sum of infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, summation, power-series

> Find the sum of infinite series 
>   $$\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{3}.\frac{1}{5^3}+\frac{1}{5}.\frac{1}{5^5}+...$$

---

I'm trying by consider this sum as S and then multiply $\frac{1}{5}$ and substract from S but i can't found any sum....

Comment: Multiply by $\frac1{5^2}$ instead

Comment: But i think  it does not apply here as coefficients are rational

Comment: What has rationality got to do with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\frac{1}{5}=x$ and $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{1}{5}x^5+...$

Thus, $$f'(x)=1+x^2+x^4+...=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$$ and
$$f(x)=\int\limits_0^x\frac{1}{1-t^2}dt=\ln\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}},$$
which after substitution $x=\frac{1}{5}$ gives the answer:
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln1.5.$$

Comment: wow nice solution...really i don't think such of that

Comment: Distaste the use of variables in the integral.

Comment: Personally, I'd write "Let $x=1/5$ ..." at the end only and not at the beginning, since you can't differentiate w.r.t. $x$ if $x=1/5$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(\tanh^{-1}(x))'=1+x^2+x^4\cdots=\frac{1}{1-x^2}= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{1-x} \right)$$

hence for 
$$\tanh^{-1}(x)=x+\frac{x^3}{3} +\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{x^7}{7}\cdots= \frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$

taking $x=\frac{1}{5}$ you have $$ \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right) = \frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{3}.\frac{1}{5^3}+\frac{1}{5}.\frac{1}{5^5}+...= \frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$